# When LinearLayout is selected are his child too?

Tags: android-linearlayout, state

When a LinearLayout state is changed to selected = "true",  are his child's state changed to selected = "true" too ?

Thanks, for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the child remains unselected. If you provide some code I will improve my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Use for it's children:

in xml

```
anroid:duplicateParentState="true"
```

or in java

```
setDuplicateParentState(true);
```